# How do I simplify this basic loop?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have code which pretty much does this.....

```
//get the row info
$Row1 = $FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow1]',0);  
$Row2 = $FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow2]',0);  
$Row3 = $FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow3]',0);  
$Row4 = $FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow4]',0);  
$Row5 = $FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow5]',0);  

//Loop 5 times. One for each row on the pitch.
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
    {
    if ($i = 1) { echo $Row1; }
    if ($i = 2) { echo $Row2; }  
    if ($i = 3) { echo $Row3; }
    if ($i = 4) { echo $Row4; }
    if ($i = 5) { echo $Row5; }
    }
```

It works, but as you can see it's not very efficient and badly designed. How would I simplify this? I know there are much smaller ways that these kind of loops can be done.

Thanks.

Comment: @sectus Why do I have to put it inside php tags then? Or are you talking about the stuff inside the for loop that I simplified?

Comment: Now it is PHP and you have two answers after editing the question :^ )

Comment: Those answers came up as I was editing it. They knew what I was saying. I did it like that because for the purposes of my question.. it wasn't needed.

Comment: You right. But i still do not understand reasons of creating your own syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the great invention of arrays:

```
//get the row info
$Row[1] = $FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow1]',0);  
$Row[2] = $FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow2]',0);  
$Row[3] = $FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow3]',0);
```

or, even more clever...

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

    $find = "div[class=ismPitchRow$i]"; 
    $Row[$i] = $FullTable->find($find,0);

}
```

do the same for echoing:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

    echo $Row[$i];

}
```

but why not do everything in 1 loop?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

    $find = "div[class=ismPitchRow$i]"; 
    echo $FullTable->find($find,0);

}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I was going to end up case and switch next which I know is also not very well formed so I knew you guys would know in seconds. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep.. I was doing that. It won't let me until about 10 mins after my post (or something like that). Have a nice evening!

Answer (score 1):

I would store `$Row1` through `$Row5` in an `array` and iterate through it with a foreach loop.

```
<?php
$YourArray = array(); 

array_push($YourArray,$FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow1]',0),$FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow2]',0),$FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow3]',0),$FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow4]',0),$FullTable->find('div[class=ismPitchRow5]',0));



foreach($YourArray as $row){
echo $row;
}
?>
```